# Why is object data undefined in method?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have some code that isn't working and I don't understand why. I boiled it down to this simple example:

```
function Load() {
    this.data = {
        isLoaded: false,
    };

    this.load1 = function() {
        console.log(this.data.isLoaded);
    };

    this.system = {
        load2: function() {
            console.log(this.data.isLoaded);
        }
    };
}

let a = new Load();
a.load1();
a.system.load2();
```

Why is this.data defined in the load1 function but undefined in the load2 function? Is there a way to get it working with the structure that I want (the second form)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.
Put `this.data` into function `scope` variable called `parentData` and you can use that value on any child.

`this` in `this.system.load2` refers `this.system` content and it won't call parent data.

```js
function Load() {
  this.data = {
    isLoaded: false,
  };
  
  var parentData = this.data;

  this.load1 = function() {
    console.log(this.data.isLoaded);
  };

  this.system = {
    load2: function() {
      console.log(parentData.isLoaded);
    }
  };
}

let a = new Load();
a.load1();
a.system.load2();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to run console.log(this). It's all about what "this" refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with scoping.

`this.data.isLoaded` is referring to the current scope of load2

```
this.system = {
        load2: function() {
            console.log(this.data.isLoaded);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work when you explicitly bind the context: `a.system.load2.call(a);`